# Call a function on page refresh using Javascript

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

```
function warnuser()
{
    return "Don't refresh the page.";
}

window.onbeforeunload = warnuser;
```

If the user refreshes the page and the user clicks 'leave this page' on confirmation box, i want to call a javascript function , otherwise not!
I am confused about how to do that.
Thank you

Comment: If refreshing the page causes a problem, you should probably be focusing your efforts on making it not be a problem instead of preventing people from doing it in the first place.

Comment: I agree with @Quentin, you probably need to be conforming to the "Post Redirect Get" paradigm.

Comment: @jezternz - There is always a way! :) But going down the hack path will forever dominate your codebase :P

Comment: I need to do that...m half the way in finishing this....just want to know how can i know whether  user clicked on 'Stay on this page' or 'leave this page' and perform some action accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to intercept the `F5` key press and setup the `onbeforeunload` handler only in that case:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 116) {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            return "Do you really want to refresh the page?";
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ejDrq/

Note that this does not work if the user *clicks* the Refresh button. It is impossible to intercept this.

Comment: What about a user click interaction with the refresh button?

Comment: I need to do that...m half the way in finishing this....just want to know how can i know whether user clicked on 'Stay on this page' or 'leave this page' and perform some action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the server side which is hosting the page then you can handle this logically with a `semaphore` ([wiki:semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))). Basically it is a spinning lock which would be implemented in their server side session. Resetting the page state if they have entered and not exited in a safe manner. Naturally, as with all spinning locks, there would have to be a safe state to clear the lock out.